# Uiview size issue Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

I'm new in storyboard and , for exercise , I created a .xib file when I put a `UItextField` and a background color , but when I execute it on iPhone 7 plus simulator I get this issue(the view doesn't fill the whole screen like in the xib file , both height and width) , while if I execute it on iPhone 6(not plus) simulator the view is correct like .xib file

[image]

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you specified any constraints, if you've what are those?

Comment: I specified this constraints : https://postimg.org/image/4oybf00cl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add auto-layout constraints by control-dragging from your view(in your case pink colored view) to superview and select (equal width, equal height). Should look something like this. Of course, you have to handle other constraints too but it seems it will only confuse you. I'd advise you to go through some auto-layout tutorials. Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: I haven't your situation because my view is in xib file. if I create view in the storyboard its ok but if create view in xib file and then link it in storyboard I have the previous problem

Comment: @alexander Shouldnt matter. autolayout should work just llke in storyboards.